# Using RHINO API to pull out a list of functions in a js file in Java

Tags: java, javascript, function, rhino

I'd like to pull out information regarding the js file I have.

Is there anyway to list the functions within the scriptable object you have using [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/apidocs/)?

Any help as always is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean, "scriptable object"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out
(1)Go to you js.jar file in command prompt
(2)you should get js> prompt
(3)type this command `load("full *.js file path");`
(4)`for(var x in global()){print(x)}`

This will print every thing in the global namespace.

hope this helps, around this u can create your own approach.